# Fetch top 3 accounts by sales rep by region in Kusto

Tags: sorting, kql, azure-data-explorer, row-number

I'm new to Kusto and I'm trying to fetch top 3 accounts with largest sales amount by sales representative by sales region and I'm struggling to get this right. Imagine a table like this:

| Sales_rep | account_id | sales_amount | region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 1234 | $100 | North |
| John Smith | 9876 | $400 | East |
| John Smith | 1729 | $1000 | North |
| John Smith | 9387 | $250 | South |
| Maria Klaus | 4567 | $300 | West |
| Maria Klaus | 7890 | $325 | South |

I want to write a KQL script that returns the top 3 accounts by sales_amount per Sales_rep per region. Pretty easy to fetch in SQL by I'm struggling with KQL. Can you please advice how to work this out? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I want to write a KQL script that returns the top 3 accounts by sales_amount per Sales_rep per region*

you could use the [`partition` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator).

```
datatable(Sales_rep: string, account_id: long, sales_amount: double, region: string)
[
    'John Smith',  1234,  100,  'North',
    'John Smith',  9876,  400,  'East',
    'John Smith',  1729,  1000, 'North',
    'John Doe',    19387, 2500, 'North',
    'John Doe',    29387, 2510, 'South',
    'Jane Doe',    39387, 2150, 'South',
    'Jane Doe',    49387, 2750, 'North',
    'Maria Klaus', 4567,  300,  'West',
    'Maria Klaus', 7890,  325,  'South',
    'Santa Klaus', 17890, 3205, 'South',
]
| partition by region ( top 3 by sales_amount desc )
```

| Sales_rep | account_id | sales_amount | region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 9876 | 400 | East |
| Jane Doe | 49387 | 2750 | North |
| John Doe | 19387 | 2500 | North |
| John Smith | 1729 | 1000 | North |
| Santa Klaus | 17890 | 3205 | South |
| John Doe | 29387 | 2510 | South |
| Jane Doe | 39387 | 2150 | South |
| Maria Klaus | 4567 | 300 | West |